# Decorator Design Pattern VS Inheritance ,Runtime VS Compile time

Tags: java, inheritance, runtime, decorator, compile-time

I saw the comment below on [this page](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2001/jw-1214-designpatterns.html?page=3). I do not understand why "decorator relationship can change at runtime" and why "inheritance relationship are fixed at compile time".

> Decorators prove more flexible than inheritance because the relationship between decorators and the objects they decorate can change at runtime, but relationships between base classes and their extensions are fixed at compile time

Comment: Because decorator relationships allow the functionality to be modified by method calls, which can be executed at run-time, without the need to recompile the code. If you depend on inheritance only, there's no way to change the behavior of a class once the application is compiled. It's easy to 'decorate' an existing object but not possible to change its class.

Comment: i only know the IOC(Inversion of Control), which construct object relationship by configuration file, when we have new services, only change configuration file, no need to recompile the code. can u tell me how decorator pattern do?

Comment: In this case, you don't even need to modify a configuration file. It can happen anytime. You can set it to be triggered by user input or any other event.

Comment: but for inheritance, i also can change implementation class triggered by user input or any other event.

Comment: Yes, but not nearly as flexible. You could have a class `Dog` and subclasses `BarkingDog` and `FluffyDog` and even `BarkingFluffyDog`. The user specifies what dog they want, and you create an instance. If they change their mind you create a _different instance_. Or you could use a decorator: they choose "barking" you create `dog = new Barking(existingDog)`. They choose "fluffy" and you say `new Fluffy(dog)` and now you have a barking, fluffy dog. At no point did you lose your original dog or have to copy properties around: you just added behaviour at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

If you have three classes, A, B and C then no matter how you inherit, you have a static relation, for example A : B and B : C.

On the other hand, if all three are decorators then you can decorate them in any order for example A(B(C)) or C(A(B)) dynamically in the same process.

Comment: these combinations are all at coding time, no at runtime, i think

Comment: Both. You can have a process in which this is the **user** who decides what is the order of decorating. Thus, the combination is not known at coding time.

Comment: u mean  "if (user input A) A(B) else A(c)", this is dynamically added funcationality at runtime? surprise.

Comment: Yep. Do you need examples? From what you write I could guess that you don't quite get the idea of decoration. Maybe you should start from a good book or an online tutorial.

Comment: thanks, i know the decorator pattern.wiki says " In object-oriented programming, the decorator pattern is a design pattern that allows behaviour to be added to an existing object dynamically." , i do not know what means for  'dynamiclly'.  from my understanding, it is runtime,

Comment: Read this as "behavior that can be added both dynamically and statically". By mentioning the dynamic behavior only, they just emphasize it. This is because it is obvious that relations between classes can be created statically.

Answer (score 3):

You can decorate an object at any time. Say you have a `FileInputStream`, you can decorate it with `BufferedInputStream` at runtime. If this was designed by class inheritance, you wouldn't be able to cast/convert your `FileInputStream` to any other type.

Comment: seems i have a little understanding, actually at runtime the decorator and decorated object relationship is fixed, but at coding time, we can choose object which need to be decorated, but why it calls addition funcationality at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

With a decorator, you're just writing a method that takes an object as input and returns some kind of wrapper.  The decorator can be arbitrarily smart, can have specialized implementations for different inputs, etcetera.

With inheritance, you have to explicitly declare the subclass at compile time and all its details, and after that point the implementation is fixed.

Comment: i still cannot understand, Decorator pattern how does it add functionality to decorated object at runtime?

Comment: You don't use the object that's being decorated; you frequently get rid of it.  Instead, you use the decorated wrapper around the object that adds some feature or behavior.

Answer (score 1):

What I think these examples dont make clear is that the decorator has a reference to the decorated class ie it uses an interface, imagine that you wanted to print out 'The End' when someone accessed the last element of a 'List', you could subclass all the classes that implement List and have 'MyArrayList, MyLinkedList, MyCopyOnWriteArrayList etc and override the get() method, (tedious Im sure you'll agree) or you could use a decorator and pass in the implementation (ie the actual list) at run time, this is referenced by its interface so then you only have one implementation of the new get method.
Consider this contrived example (below), the point is I can pass in any implementation of List to the ListDecorator and It will work, imagine doing this with inheritance and Im sure you'll understand why decorators are sometimes better.

```
package decorator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListDecorator {

    List realList;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            // Here we are decorating an ArrayList but it could be anything
            // that implements the List interface.
        ListDecorator ld = new ListDecorator( new ArrayList() );
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
            ld.add( i );

        for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
            System.out.println("[j]="+ld.get(j) );
    }
    ListDecorator(List realList){
        this.realList = realList;
    }
    public void add(Object o){
        realList.add( o );
    }
    public Object get(int i){
        if(i == realList.size() -1)
            System.out.println("The end");

        return realList.get(i);
    }
}
```